# A linear consequence of the Michael selection theorem

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

Assume that $X$ and $Y$ are two Banach spaces and $T:X\to Y$ is a bounded surjective linear operator.

A consequence of the Michael selection theorem is that:"There is a continuous function $g:Y\to X$ such that $T\circ g=Id_{Y}$".

> Can we always find a linear map $g$ as above?

Comment: Would the following be an answer? There is no bounded linear 1-1 mapping $\ell^\infty/c_0 \to \ell^\infty$ Corollary 20 in [link](http://www.helsinki.fi/~hjkjunni/top7.pdf)

Comment: The title is not very apt: the previous comment explains why. Your question is equivalent to: "is a closed subspace of a Banach space always complemented?" and the answer is "usually no".

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/411119/does-there-exist-such-a-closed-subspace-of-normed-linear-space

Comment: There are always a *continuous* selection and *linear* selection (playing with Hamel bases) but of course not always a *continuous linear* one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer No. Just to add that the example that there is no bounded linear 1-1 mapping 
$\ell^\infty/c_0 \to \ell^\infty$ is due to Phillips in 1940 (as commented in the link provided by Yemon Choi above, discussing the complementary subspace problem, 
also credited to Phillips in the link to pdf I found and posted).